# how to mainpulate data in datatable using loop,array any how and print in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I want to print only the  first column, but this code is printing whole table.

What is the correct way of doing so?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Populating a DataTable from database.
        DataTable dt = this.GetData();

        //Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        //Table start.
        html.Append("<table border = '1'>");

        //Building the Header row.

        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {   
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("</tr>");
        counter = 0;

        //Building the Data rows.

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you did is that you are traversing your columns even though you only want to show your first column.

Therefore you need to not traverse the columns - via your foreach loop - but get the first column by using `dt.Columns[0]`. Take a look below:

```
//Get the first column from datatable
var firstColumn = dt.Columns[0]; 

//Build the Header row.

html.Append("<tr>");

html.Append("<th>");
html.Append(firstColumn.ColumnName);
html.Append("</th>");

html.Append("</tr>");
counter = 0;

//Build the Data rows.

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    html.Append("<tr>");

    html.Append("<td>");
    html.Append(row[firstColumn.ColumnName]); 
    html.Append("</td>");

    html.Append("</tr>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

columnName is the column which you want the results from datatable

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string file = row.Field<string>(columnName);
}
```